# How do I stop R Studio and knitr from associating my .Rmd PowerPoint with an app other then MS PowerPoint

Tags: r, macos, r-markdown, powerpoint, knitr

I am making my first rmarkdown for PowerPoint.  I started a new .Rmd file from RStudio.  I saved it to my working directory.  When knitting it creates the .pptx file (I've confirmed the file is in the wd and it will open), but after rendering it tries to open another app (called thebrain, it is mind mapping software), not PowerPoint to open it.  I've looked in Finder, using "Get Info" and verified that PowerPoint is the app associated with .pptx files, so it should not be a MacOS issue. I assume this is an RStudio, rmarkdown or knitr issue.  I've searched using Google an on stackoverflow but cannot find anyone else dealing with this.

I've looked at the [RStudio PowerPoint Trouble Shooting](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006283914) page, but it does not address.

I do not have reproducible code, but it is basically:

```
Open New .Rmd from RStudio, using .PowerPoint as the selection.  Save the default file without changing anything.  knit to PowerPoint.
```

The error message is:  *The document ed_wic_2020_presentatin.pptx could not be opened.  TheBrain cannot open files in the "Office Open XML presentation: format.*

I'm running R Studio Version 1.2.1335, R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree", the latest and greatest version of PowerPoint for MacOs and MacOS Catalina 10.15.r

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Interesting problem - sounds like a macOS issue rather than an Rmarkdown issue - Have you tried changing the 'Get Info / open with app' to something else (selecting 'change all') then change it back to MS powerpoint again? Also maybe try uninstalling TheBrain?

Comment: I tried rendering an example Rmd to pptx using Mac OS X 10.15.4 / RStudio 1.2.1335 / R 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) -- "Action of the Toes" and PowerPoint v16.35 (20030802) and had no issues - what happens when you render the example from https://github.com/sol-eng/powerpoint/tree/master/examples/bank on your system?